# Eshell history manipulation (quick string substitution) doesn't work

Tags: emacs, elisp, eshell

I'm using eshell in emacs.

In bash, when I execute:

```
ls test
^ls^ll^
```

it executes the last command again with the ls changed to ll, like this:

```
ll test
```

How can I do it in eshell?
When I did this:

```
ls test
^ls^ll^
```

or:

```
!!:s/ls/ll/
```

eshell gave an error:

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, 108
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a bug in eshell. The behavior described by the OP is the same for me using a vanilla Emacs 24.3.1. I looked into it a bit, but I'm having trouble getting a proper backtrace even after `(setq eshell-handle-errors nil)`, `(setq debug-on-error t)`, etc. Anybody have any insights?

Comment: The eshell documentation has historically been scant, but eshell appears to have been written to provide the bash behavior noted above (cf. function `eshell-history-reference`). Docs like [Mastering Eshell](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/12/13/complete-guide-mastering-eshell/) say that eshell quick substitution "appears to be buggy" (Dec 2010).

Answer (score 0):

eshell has built-in variables

see:

(info "(eshell) Built-ins")

It think you want `$_', which refers to the last argument of the last command.

If you don't have the info installed for eshell (the documentation), it's available here:

https://github.com/nicferrier/eshell-manual